# Problem when trying to push files to from vs code to github repo

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Im trying to push a file from vs code to a github repo of the same name

Hi Im getting this output:
fatal: unable to access 'https://https://github.com/ianecross/apple.git/': Could not resolve host: https

seems to have appended https// twice.

It does this when i do:

> git remote add origin https://github.com/ianecross/apple.git

> git push -u origin main

or just:

> github.com/ianecross/apple.git

without the 'https://', i still get same error

Any help would be most appreciated, thanks

Comment: However, you do know that you can't really push with `https:` to GitHub, right? You need to switch to SSH.

Comment: Can you show the output of `git remote -vv` ?

Comment: @matt I do HTTPS pushes to GitHub fine, all that was changed is the requirement to use access tokens not the account password (not the problem here), there is no need to switch to SSH.

Comment: Is there any value containing `insteadOf` in `git config -l`?

Comment: for some reason https:// gets attached to the beginning of the url twice when i attempt to to push the file